# Loops in Database vs in application

Tags: java, mysql, sql, vb.net, loops

Soon I'm planning to rewrite my application to Java (from VB.NET) and since I got that chance I'm planning to do a lot of code cleanup in the new app as the one written in VB.NET is my first application and it gone pretty big for one person.

Anyway, I've been thinking about using loops in MySQLs Stored Procedures (which I hate, I can't really tell why) and if maybe it is better to query database for data I need to perform loop with then use client PC to perform all those operations and then send the data back to database.

An example of operation: in my applications there are goods coming in and out. When I'm selling goods I need to connect sells with previously bought goods with First in First out rule. For example I bought 10 bananas, then another 10 and then 20. Then I want to sell 30 of them so I link first 10 bananas and it leaves me with 20 so I link it with another 10 so it leaves me with 10 and then I link it with the last batch of bananas but I don't use all of them so I got 20 bananas left on me.

The way I see it:

1. Loops in Stored Procedures should be faster because it got all the data in one place but I'm not sure if it is a good practice to perform this kind of operations in database.
2. Loops in application needs to get data from database and then send it back so that may make it bad but personally I think loops in other languages than SQL are easier to read and debug.

What do you think?

Comment: In general:  loops, bad; SQL set-based operations, good.  You might be surprised how often you can replace loops with a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Before you go far with stored procedures, try out a small case and make sure it helps you. MySQL stored procedures can make your application much slower.

Comment: It's a tough question, I don't think it can be answered without being too subjective. Try it out which approach is faster, more secure and probably portable.

Comment: Well I tried to replace that loop with using INSERT INTO alongside SELECT statement but I couldn't make it. It maybe my lack of knownledge as I never studied any language more than getting to know the basics. Most of it I've learned on my own.

Comment: Most people here have learned skills on their own, but they didn't stop at the basics. If your approach to problem solving is "I tried, but I couldn't make it", then you'll never learn properly.

Comment: Well that thing wasn't really a problem for me because I had already done it with loop, I was just checking if I can make it differently. Also I don't always have time for checking things because I'm the only developer in my company and I also take care of network, software and hardware. Basically everything related to IT. And people always come to me with new suggestions to the program which has to be done now or even a day before.

Comment: @FilipK perhaps you should ask for help in re-writing your loops into selects. For this question you already got your answer: test both approaches and use whichever is faster.

Comment: beyond performance, youll want to consider the proximity of the database to the application and the reliability of that connection (same machine, same network, separate networks over the internet?)...chatty calls often have a higher chance of failure (beyond the performance concerns of chatty calls)

Comment: For loop, I think it all have to do with how many time you would need to query the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to answer objectively I'd say: It depends on the complexity of your query, the quantity of Data you need to  process, and the DBMS you're using.

I'd also like to add that just because data is processed within the database, it doesn't has to be faster than you're application - The main quality of databases lies within SQL set-based operations, as Gordon Linoff already wrote.

If you're not analyzing several hundredthousands of datasets, then probably you don't need to worry about performance much, but more about which is the most maintainable way.

In my experience a combination of simple selects providing filtered Data and smart loops processing them within in my application always did a good Job, as it was maintainable and reasonably fast.

In your Example this means: Use SQL to get your stock filtered for Bananas and sort them by date (obviously). Then loop through your results in the application and stop once you got the desired quantity of Bananas

Using windowed Sum-Function you might even limit the query results to the point, that the cumlative sum of the quantity passes a certain value.